# Vim: Error message on sourcing, but not on start up

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

I'm pretty new to Vim/gVim and am probably doing something wrong. What I want to do is completely reload my configuration (like a restart), but while gVim is running (keep the current session). Here are the steps I take and their result:

1. Start gVim → No error
2. `:so $MYVIMRC` → No error
3. ```
   :so $MYGVIMRC
   Error detected while processing ~\.gvimrc:
   line    1:
   E185: Cannot find color scheme 'kolor'
   ```

When I do step 3 before step 2 I don't get any error, but what if I want to source the files multiple times in the same session? Do I have to unload them first somehow, or do I have to save the session, restart gVim and reload the session again each time?

---

*~/.gvimrc*:

```
set runtimepath=$HOME/.vim,$VIMRUNTIME,$HOME/.vim/after
execute pathogen#infect()
```

*~/.gvimrc*:

```
colorscheme kolor
```

*~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim*

*~/.vim/bundle/vim-kolor/colors/kolor.vim*

---

Vim 7.4, patches 1-2054
Windows & Xubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy solution for this problem. Try and move the `kolor.vim` file to the `~/.vim/colors` . Also, you don't really need to do changes to the runtime path. Vundles does it automatically for you. Seems because you manually modified your runtime path `set runtimepath=$HOME/.vim,$VIMRUNTIME,$HOME/.vim/after`
, it is confusing Vim. 

`set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`

Let me know if it fixes your problem. One good rule for thumb is to not put anything in your .vimrc file that you don't fully understand.

Comment: Having the add-on(s) in the default location works fine, just not with pathogen (and maybe other managers). However if I do `set runtimepath+=...` instead of `set runtimepath=...` it works too. Though when I copy the default runtimepath and set that (with =) plus mine (with +=) in *.vimrc* it doesn't work. So I guess vim doesn't like the runtimepath to completely be reset. I wanted to exclude the *vimfiles* directories that are set for windows and exactly define where vim should look for files and not get problems with other directorys that *might* contain junk files.